# Order by date column in nhibernate is working as order by string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, queryover

I am trying to sorty data using date column but the column is sorting as string not as date. how to solve this problem?

Code:

```
var projection = Projections.SqlFunction("lower", NHibernateUtil.String,Projections.Property("datecolumn1"));

if(order="desc")queryOver = queryOver.OrderBy(projection).Desc;
else queryOver = queryOver.OrderBy(projection).Asc;
```

Result:(sorted by ascending)

```
8/7/2012 5:34 AM
11/7/2012 7:21 AM
11/7/2012 7:21 AM
11/7/2012 7:21 AM
11/7/2012 7:21 AM
8/27/2012 9:35 AM
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The snippet above shows that the there is a `string` projection. So the result is sorted as a set of string values. (and that could lead to different results dependent on sql server default `DateTime.ToString` format).

To sort it by date add a different projection:

```
var projection = Projections.Property("datecolumn1"));
```

Now it should be ordered by native SQL Server `DateTime` type